# how to remove deleted faces's line?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I deleted vertices, edges and faces on the red faces. But the lines remain on the object. 
I can not even select the lines.(including vertex, edge, face)

how can I remove the lines?

Comment: You probably pressed the letter **P** and separated that section into another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most propably became another object, try exiting from the edit mode and selecting those lines

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the modes of selection to vertices, edges and faces.
2. And after pressing <kbd>X</kbd>, try deleting vertices faces and edges.

[image]

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots. The current ones are quite hard to see. Thanks.